# estimate of a slope in the simple linear regression model $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\epsilon$

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I have two formulas for estimate of a slope in the  simple linear regression model $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\epsilon$:

- $\hat{\beta_1}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum^N_{i=1}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$
- $\hat{\beta_1}=(X_{1\times N}'X_{N\times1})^{-1}X'_{1\times N}Y_{N\times 1}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^Nx_iy_i}{\sum^N_{i=1}x_i^2}$

These formulas are not equivalent, but are used in different literature as a main formulas to find the estimate of $\beta_1$. When we use each formula? what is the motivation to use averages of x's and y's in the first formula?

Second part of my question.

If I want to find a variance of $\hat{\beta_1}$ from the first formula
$$Var(\hat{\beta_1})=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\bar{x})^2Var(y_i-\bar{y})}{\big[\sum^N_{i=1}(x_i-\bar{x})^2\big]^2}=\frac{(\sigma^2-\frac{\sigma^2}{N})}{\sum^N_{i=1}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$
but the answer should be 
$$\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum^N_{i=1}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First question

The first $\hat{\beta}_1$ is the OLS estimator of the model
\begin{equation}
 y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i
\end{equation}
The second OLS estimator corresponds to the model 
\begin{equation}
 y_i = \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon
\end{equation}
i.e. one with no intercept. Redo the math by assuming the first model, i.e. in matrix form you have
\begin{equation}
 X = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & x_1 \\
  1 & x_2 \\
  \vdots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_n
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and you will see that both estimators are the same.

---

### Second question

Let's rewrite the numerator of $\hat{\beta_1}$

\begin{align}
\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})
= \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})y_i - \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})\bar{y} \tag{1}
\end{align}
Let's work with the second term a bit
\begin{align}
\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})\bar{y}
&= \bar{y}\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})\\
&= \bar{y}\left(\left(\sum_i x_i\right) - n\bar{x}\right)\\
&= \bar{y}\left(n\bar{x} - n\bar{x}\right)\\
&= 0
\end{align}
So equation $(1)$ becomes 
\begin{equation}
\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})
= \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})y_i
= \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i )
\end{equation}
You now get
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(\hat{\beta_1})
& = \text{Var} \left(\frac{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \right) \\
&= \text{Var} \left(\frac{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i )}{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \right)\\
&= \text{Var} \left(\frac{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})\epsilon_i}{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \right)\\
&=  \frac{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2\text{Var}(\epsilon_i)}{\left(\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2\right)^2}\\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \\
\end{align}